# Hibernate one to one null foreign key while saving

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have problem with one to one relationship - after save foreign key is always being set as null even if I have associated object. I am using Hibernate 4.3.7.Final with Spring 4.0.0.RELEASE and MySql 5.6 database.

In my situation after I save LawFirmProfile object column lawFirm_id with reference to LawFirm is always null.

**Entities:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="usr_lawfirm")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="userId")
public class LawFirm extends User implements Serializable{

    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "lawFirm")
    private LawFirmProfile lawFirmProfile = new LawFirmProfile();


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="lf_profile")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class LawFirmProfile implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    ...

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lawFirm_id")
    private LawFirm lawFirm;

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr_user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"email"})
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    ...
}
```

**Here is code responsible for saving this record:**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveProfile(LawFirm lawFirm){
    LawFirmProfile profile = lawFirm.getLawFirmProfile();
    userDao.update(lawFirm);
    profile.setLawFirm(lawFirm);
    lawFirmProfileDao.saveOrUpdate(profile);
}
```

**Hibernate and Spring config:**

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>system.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" 
      class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${c3p0.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${c3p0.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${c3p0.maxIdleTime}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value ="${c3p0.maxStatements}" /> 

</bean>

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test." />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Dao is also spring bean with methods annotated as @Transactional.

During save I got following error from C3p0. However the LawFirmProfile record was saved in database but reference to LawFirm was null.

```
2016-01-07 13:25:26,084 Participating in existing transaction
2016-01-07 13:25:26,095 Adding transactional method 'saveOrUpdate' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2016-01-07 13:25:26,096 Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
2016-01-07 13:25:26,096 Found thread-bound Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.LawFirm#55]],collectionKeys=[CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.User.sendMessages#55], CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.User.payments#55], CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.LawFirm.invitations#55], CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.User.receivedMessages#55], CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.User.attachments#55], CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.LawFirm.legalCases#55]]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6350cb30 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4d4bef40 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@34487a65 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@25b97b4 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4b44aba1 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@95ffda2 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7d049b7c collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@397c2a03 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
2016-01-07 13:25:26,096 Participating in existing transaction
Hibernate: insert into lf_profile (city, postCode, street, krsNumber, name, nip, regon, email, phone, website, description, latitude, longitude, lawFirm_id, lawFirmType, lawyerNumber, pricePerHour, solicitorNumber, specialization) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2016-01-07 13:25:26,126 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner@6db73230: Adding task to queue -- com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@7e308448
2016-01-07 13:25:26,127 cxnStmtMgr.statementSet( com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@40a126ad ).size(): 7
2016-01-07 13:25:26,127 checkoutStatement: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 7; checked out: 1; num connections: 1; num keys: 7
2016-01-07 13:25:26,142 checkinStatement(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 7; checked out: 0; num connections: 1; num keys: 7
2016-01-07 13:25:26,142 Initiating transaction commit
2016-01-07 13:25:26,143 Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.LawFirm#55], EntityKey[com.efsf.gateone.lawfirm.model.LawFirmProfile#68]],collectionKeys=[CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.User.sendMessages#55], CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.User.payments#55], CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.LawFirm.invitations#55], CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.User.receivedMessages#55], CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.User.attachments#55], CollectionKey[com.efsf.gateone.user.model.LawFirm.legalCases#55]]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6350cb30 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4d4bef40 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@34487a65 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@25b97b4 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4b44aba1 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@95ffda2 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7d049b7c collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@397c2a03 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
Hibernate: update usr_user set email=?, lastLogin=?, login=?, name=?, password=?, phone=?, premiumUntil=?, status=?, surname=? where userId=?
2016-01-07 13:25:26,145 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache ----> CACHE HIT
2016-01-07 13:25:26,145 checkoutStatement: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 7; checked out: 1; num connections: 1; num keys: 7
2016-01-07 13:25:26,147 checkinStatement(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 7; checked out: 0; num connections: 1; num keys: 7
2016-01-07 13:25:26,147 Converting Throwable to SQLException...
java.lang.NullPointerException
at   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.maybeDirtyTransaction(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:2520)
at   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.getMaxRows(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1403)
at  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:530)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.release(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:407)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.releaseStatements(AbstractBatchImpl.java:173)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:76)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3281)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453)
```

I try everything to make it work but without success.

Comment: In your LawFirmProfile Class you have a parameter called lawFirm_id correct? I don't see it in the code above but maybe you removed it for brevity?

Comment: I have lawFirm attribute while lawFirm_id is column name for LawFirm reference.

Comment: Can you show your DB structure for those three classes?

Comment: Of course - here is DB structure: http://hastebin.com/ugeneteqez.sql

Comment: Ok, I'm in the middle of typing up an aswer that will hopefully work for you. One question. Can you make changes to the DB? lf_profile does not need its own unique id column since it has a onetoone mapping with usr_lawfirm, so just using lawFirm_id as the primary key will work.

Comment: Yes I can make DB structure changes

Comment: Ok, then maybe also rename lawFirm_id to lawFirmId to be consistent with the rest of the naming schema. :) Then you can remove the @Column attribute from my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your `LawFirm` class reference to `LawFirmProfile` should look like this

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}) // The cascade part is probably optional
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private LawFirmProfile lawFirmProfile;
```

Also when your LawFirm class Id gets updated be sure to also update the LawFirmProfile class. It should look something like this:

```
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    if(LawFirmProfile != null) {
        LawFirmProfile.setLawFirmId(userId);
    }

    this.userId = userId;
}
```

Now for your LawFirmProfile class. Ensure that is has a parameter `lawFirmId`

```
@Column(name="lawFirm_id")
@Id
private int lawFirmId;

... lawFirmId getter and setter....
```

Also ensure you LawFirmProfile class has a reference to LawFirm

```
@MapsId
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="lawFirmId")
private LawFirm lawFirm;
```

With getter and setter, with setter like this:

```
public void setLawFirm(LawFirm lawFirm) {
    this.lawFirm = lawFirm;

    if(lawFirm != null) {
        lawFirmId = lawFirm.getUserId();
    }
}
```

Then as discussed in the comments remove the `id` column from lf_profile and make lawFirm_id the primary key.